# is there a solution to fetch all id in the Firestore?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i want to fecth all the id not just 888888888 and get the orders for each id
[image]

Comment: Going forward please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is known as a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) in Firestore.

It'd looks like this:

```
db.collectionGroup("orders").get()
```

The above reads all collections called `orders` no matter where they are located (top-level, under an `tels` doc, or under any other doc.

---

To determine what `tels` doc a specific order is under, you can navigate up `ref.parent.parent` of the order snapshot:

```
db.collectionGroup("orders").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
  querySnapshot.forEach((orderSnapshot) => {
    const orderRef = orderSnapshot.ref;
    const ordersRef = orderRef.parent;
    const telRef = orderRef.parent;
    console.log(refRef.id); // 8888888888
  })
})
```